# Как прижать span к тексту

Tags: html, css

```css
span {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 44px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #6C0287;
}
```

```html
 <span>“</span> <p class="blockquote-text">
                    GAME OVER —
                    это место незабываемых впечатлений
                </p><span>”</span>
            </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Куда прижать? Зачем? Можете дать больше информации? :)

Comment: Быть может span нужно вставить в p, ну или в для p line-height: 0;

Comment: Losing is Fun, так сказать

Comment: Исходя из ваших данных, для тега ```p``` сделать ```margin: 0;```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так, просто span переместить в p

```
    <p class="blockquote-text">
      <span>“</span>
      GAME OVER —
      это место незабываемых впечатлений
      <span>”</span>
    </p>
```

Или так, через css (в таком варианте не забудьте из html убрать span)

```
    .blockquote-text::before {
        content: "“"; /* Добавляем символ */
        padding-right: 7px; /* Расстояние от символа до текста */
        font-weight: 900; /* жирность */
        font-size: 44px; /* шрифт */
        color: #6C0287; /* цвет */
   }
   .blockquote-text::after {
        content: "”"; /* Добавляем символ */
        padding-left: 7px; /* Расстояние от символа до текста */
        font-weight: 900; /* жирность */
        font-size: 44px; /* шрифт */
        color: #6C0287; /* цвет */
   }
```